# Difference between fread(&c, 1, 1, input) and fgetc(input) for reading one byte

Tags: c, file, file-io, stdio

I'm currently trying to read in a PNG file, one byte at a time, and I'm getting different results when I use `fread((void*), size_t, size_t, FILE*)` and `fgetc(FILE*)`.

I essentially want to "Read one byte at a time until the file ends", and I do so in two different ways. In both cases, I open the image I want in binary mode through:

`FILE* input = fopen( /* Name of File */, 'rb');`

And store each byte in a character, `char c`

fread: `while( fread(&c, 1, 1, input) != 0) //read until there are no more bytes read`

fgetc:
`while( (c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) //Read while EOF hasn't been reached`

In the `fread` case, I read all the bytes I need to do. The reading function stops at the end of the file, and I end up printing all 380,000 bytes (which makes sense, as the input file is a 380kB file).

However, in the `fgetc` case, I stop once I reach a byte with a value of `ff` (which is -1, the value of the macro `EOF`.

My question is, if both functions are doing the same thing, reading one byte at a time, how does fread know to continue reading even if it comes across a byte with a value of `EOF`? And building off of this, how does fread know when to stop if `EOF` is passed when reading the file?

Comment: `EOF` has an *int* value of `-1`, not a `char` value. Typically, `EOF` is not a legal byte value at all. If you store it to a `char`, sure, you can't tell the difference, but that's why `fgetc` returns `int`, not `char`, because `0xff` is a perfectly legal return value that *doesn't* mean `EOF`.

Comment: You are basing your conclusion in a false premise, namely "*`ff` (which is -1, the value of the macro `EOF`*" is false. It's the type of `c` which is causing this confusion. Change `c`'s type to `int` and the problem shall disappear. Google something like "*why does `fgetc()` return `int` instead of `char`*?".

Comment: @ShadowRanger Okay. That's making sense a bit more... The way I'm understanding it now is: `EOF` is of type `INT`, which is 4 bytes. `EOF` has a value of -1, which means four consecutive bytes have the pattern "`0xff`. Therefore, because in the fgetc scenario, I only ever read 1 `0xff`, and I truncate the `EOF` bytes to 1 bytes, I trick the program (erroneously) into finishing early... Is this a reasonable interpretation of the problem?

Comment: @ricardo: No. The filesystem knows hiw long the fike is because it keeps the length in the file metadata. It does not put any sort of sentinel value after the file's data. If you try to read the file and the read pointer is at the end of the file, the eof flag in the `FILE` struct will be set and an EOF indication will be returned from whatever library function you used to read the file. In the case of `fgetc`, the EOF return value is negative, which cannit be confused with a character code because `fgetc` always returns non-negative character codes, even if `char` is a signed type.

Comment: ... which is why `fgetc` returns an `int` and not a `char`. Many of the possible return values of `fgetc` could not be represented as a (signed) `char`. Storing such a value in a (signed) `char` is Undefined Behaviour, although gcc reliably sign extends the last 8 bits of the return value. (In most architectures, "sign extends" is a fancy way of saying "just pretends the 8thbkast bit is the sign" but it us theoretically possible for the `char` type to have more than 8 bits.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. `EOF` (and many actual character codes) cannot be stored in a `char` and attempting to do so will result in Undefined Behaviour. So don't do that. Store the return value in an `int`.

Comment: "We can't store EOF, an int, in a char"... Why is that? If we simply typecast from int to a char, if the value is in the range [-128, 127], we haven't lost any information. Many posts I've seen give the value of EOF to be -1, which is possible to represent with a 1-byte value. In your comment, you mentioned that if we're at the end of a file, the return value of fgetc is negative. Why can't we store this in a signed character? The way I've seen it, char's can store any value in the range [-128, 127], so if it's in the range, I see no reason we can't use a char.

Comment: @ricardo: there are 257 possible return values from `fgetc`; 256 different characters and EOF. An 8-bit datatype can have 256 different values. So at least one doesn't fit. Also, as I said, `fgetc` always returns positive values for characters. 128 of those can't be represented in a signed char. If char is unsigned, all the character codes can be represented but EOF (which is always negative) cannot.

Comment: Okay that's making a bit more sense now. So if I wanted to go through each character using fgetc, I would do: `while(! feof(input))` and inside the loop just `fgetc(input)`. Thank you very much for the answers!

Comment: @Ricardo: If you want to go through each character using fgetc, you do it the way you were doing it. Just make c an int instead of a char. `while(!feof(input))` is almost never correct, because `feof` is not set until *after* the EOF has been reported. So the last iteration will still return EOF; the feof call doesn't protect you.

Comment: @Ricardo: As  side issue, if you are planning on using the various functions from `ctype.h` (such as `isalpha`), you need to be aware that they expect their argument to be an `int` with a non-negative value for any character, or `EOF` (which will always return `false` but is a legal input). In other words, they expect exactly the `int` returned by `fgetc`. The common usage of passing a `char` to `isalpha` will produce Undefined Behaviour if the argument happens to be negative, as it will be with signed `char` for characters outside of US-ASCII.

Comment: The reason that this fact is not more widely known is that the GNU libc implementation goes to some trouble to hide this error, by allowing negative arguments down to -128. However, other libc implementations might not be so generous, so it's not clear to me tht glibc is actually doing you a favour.