# C program inside docker container ignores fgetc(stdin)

Tags: c, docker, stdin, fgetc

I have a C program running inside a Docker container and calling a function getkey() as below:

```c
int getkey() {

int ch;
struct termios orig_term_attr, new_term_attr;

/* set terminal to raw mode */

   tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &orig_term_attr);
   memcpy(&new_term_attr, &orig_term_attr, sizeof(struct termios));
   new_term_attr.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
   new_term_attr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
   new_term_attr.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
   tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &new_term_attr);

   ch = fgetc(stdin);  /* read one char from stdin stream without blocking. Returns EOF (-1) if none available */

   tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &orig_term_attr);  /* restore original terminal attributes */

   return ch;
}
```

In a host or VM terminal window this works fine, but inside a container fgetc(stdin) input is ignored. By ignore I mean if I press keys they show up on the container command line after the program finishes. The docker run command line is:

```
docker run -it keybd_test /bin/bash
```

I have tried with --init and with -a stdin -a stdout -a stderr. I suspect it has something to do with temporarily placing the terminal in raw mode, but in searching the closest I can find is [ctrl-C handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350335/docker-not-responding-to-ctrlc-in-terminal)

Is there something I'm missing in the docker run command ? Is there a known issue with terminal raw mode inside containers ?

Docker --version shows 20.10.17, build 100c70180f

Comment: What happens if you replace `fgetc()` with something like `read( STDIN_FILENO,...)`?  Or set `stdin()` to non-buffered with `setbuf( stdin, NULL );`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle dang, good catch !  setbuf(stdin, NULL) has no effect, but  read(fileno(stdin), (char*)&ch, 1) fixes the problem. Note that I used stdin(fileno) vs STDIN_FILENO, as per https://rtems-users.rtems.narkive.com/dIl6m5yS/fileno-stdin-versus-stdin-fileno-and-friends they can conceivably be different. Other than EOF, what is the difference between fgetc() and read( one char ) ? I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225595/difference-between-freadc-1-1-input-and-fgetcinput-for-reading-one-byte which focuses on EOF but not buffering or other underlying terminal comm